# Finding what an alternating series converges to

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

One of my homework problems was to determine whether the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n-4}}{(2n-1)!}$ converges, and if it does, find what it converges to.

I used the ratio test to show that it converges absolutely. To find what it converges to, I first multiplied it by $x^3$:

$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n-4}}{(2n-1)!} \implies x^3f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$.

I know that this is almost the Taylor series of $\sin x$, but I couldn't remember whether or not we proved this in class. So, I said:

"By Taylor's formula, we have:

$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\dots + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} + R_n(x)$, where $R_n(x)$ is the error term.

$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$.

For all $c$, we have $f^{(n+1)}(c) \leq 1$. This means that:

$R_n(x) \leq \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$.

Hence, by the Remainder Estimation Theorem, the series converges to $f(x)$ for all $x$."

I then concluded that the original series must converge to $-\frac{\sin x}{x^3}$.

Is my solution correct? Also, are my arguments easy to read or is it confusing?

I apologize if this is a trivial question, but I don't have anyone to ask this and I want to make sure I understand what I am doing.

Comment: Are you sure the index starts at $n=0$? Or that the denominator is $(2n-1)!$? If yes, how do you define $(-1)!$ in this context?

Comment: When you say $R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$ it seems like you have changed the definition of $f(x)$ $\sin x$.  Why doesn't it say $R_n(x)=\frac{\sin^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$?  In the next couple of sentences you are also saying $f$ when you mean $\sin$ I think.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote the general formula for the error term, forgetting that $f(x)$ is already defined. I will change it to $\sin x$. Thank you!

Comment: I had not noticed that the first term does not make sense. I assume my teacher didn’t notice it, either. I’ll notify him, and change the start of the index to $n=1$. Thank you for noticing!